# Convert magento url to module, controller, action, parameters

Tags: php, magento

I want to be able to get the controller, action and parameters for a specific url. Even if this url is a permalink or any other abstraction.

eg list(controller, action, parameters) = route('http://example.com/controller/action/parameter/1/')

or list(controller, action, parameters) = route(http://example.com/some_store_item.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    $module = $request->getModuleName();
    $controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $action = $request->getActionName();
    $parameters = $request->getParams();
/* params provide list of parameters of url in array format 
For getting indiviusal parameter use */

 $Id = $request->getParam('id');
```